# Why does no one sell pressed tofu?

Tags: tofu

After following recommendations found online for pressed tofu (as in tofu that was squeezed to pour out more water. Shrinking to about 40% in size), it seems to be a really good/simple meat alternative, rehology wise and taste wise (less of that... tofu taste.. allowing it to soak more of the gravies added to it!).
Yet, no one sells pressed tofu, and pressing tofu is a mess with home appliances.
More: the pressed tofu should provide higher protein content.

So, am I missing a point here? Why does no one sell it pressed instead of selling a presser? Seems like a product waiting to be discovered. Hence putting this here for anyone working in the industry to pick it.

Attaching a few links to videos describing it. After tasting it myself I must say it is the real deal, better then seitan and tofu / tvp...

https://youtu.be/LwDYQxdc5_Q
https://youtu.be/YUIDd7wRcg4

Comment: They do sell it. You didn't look hard enough. "Why" questions don't work on the stack exchange format, because, as in this case,  the only people who could give an accurate answer would be the tofu companies who *don't* sell it.

Comment: Please bring an example if you can. And, well stackoverflow format ... yes. I put it here to be heard. Wont open a blog for it

Comment: Personally I find super-firm tofu rubbery and unpleasant.

Comment: When I've pressed tofu (I admit, only twice), it acted like a sponge and would soak up marinades just after you took off the pressure ... I suspect that pre-pressed tofu wouldn't do that.

Comment: I see it at most of the Asian groceries in my area. Based on the languages on the packaging, it's marketed to Vietnamese and Chinese-speaking customers.

Comment: The most logic answer is that water is cheap so it's easier to sell "more" tofu. It's like shelledn and unshelled pistacchios. The price for kg is the same but with shells you pay, well, for shells.

Comment: I think customers would be willing to pay more if some hard work would be spared from them.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY perhaps it’s different where you live, but at my local supermarket pistachios without the shell are £14 per kilo and with the shell are £20. I still get your point of course, was just curious whether it was universally true.

Comment: The minute someone closes a question of you on stack overflow, you just know it was a good question :) The lifeless swarm of unpaid "moderators" here are a monument to the general stupidity of the most of mankind. And the problem is, the most they get bored of their life, the more they play moderators. Get a life! Stop closing questions...

Answer (score 1):

Pressed (firm and extra firm) tofu is widely available, though perhaps not near you.  You can also [further press store bought tofu at home](https://www.thespruceeats.com/how-to-press-tofu-3376642) to remove excess moisture.  Just put it between absorbent layers, and add weight to the top.

Comment: Extra firm is indeed sold online, but I fear it is not nearly as squeezed and elastic. Maybe it's the title: "firm" which doesn't ressemble (for me) pressed. Point is, tofu pressing is still a practice wildly used, and I suspect for a reason.